# How to solve flutter web api cors error only with dart code?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, request

It seems like CORS error is well-known issue in the web field. But I tried flutter web for the first time ever and I faced critical error.

The code below worked well in app version when it was running on iOS device, but when i tested the same code on Chrome with web debugging from beta channel, it encountered CORS error.

Other Stack Overflow answers explained how to solve the CORS issue with server-side files of their projects, but I have totally no idea what is server thing and how to deal with their answers. The error message from Chrome console is below:

> [  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://kapi.kakao.com/v1/payment/ready' from origin
> 'http://localhost:52700' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  ]

So, what I want to do is to solve above 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin header' issue ONLY WITH DART CODE! Code below is what I've tried to solve these issues only with my main.dart.

```
onPressed: () async {
      var res =
          await http.post('https://kapi.kakao.com/v1/payment/ready', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf8'), headers: {
        'Authorization': 'KakaoAK $_ADMIN_KEY',
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'KakaoAK $_ADMIN_KEY',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD",
      }, body: {
        'cid': 'TC0ONETIME',
        'partner_order_id': 'partner_order_id',
        'partner_user_id': 'partner_user_id',
        'item_name': 'cool_beer',
        'quantity': '1',
        'total_amount': '22222',
        'vat_amount': '2222',
        'tax_free_amount': '0',
        'approval_url': '$_URL/kakaopayment',
        'fail_url': '$_URL/kakaopayment',
        'cancel_url': '$_URL/kakaopayment'
      });
      Map<String, dynamic> result = json.decode(res.body);
      print(result);
    },
```

Even though I actually had the header `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` which most other answers recommended, the Chrome console printed same error message. Weird thing is that the same code made successful request in mobileApp version. So I think this is only problem with flutter WEB VERSION.

Hope somebody can figure it out and suggest only-dart code to resolve the issue in my main.dart!

Comment: This could be the solution you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/37765371/13758642

Comment: Using [Osman Tuzcu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10757031/osman-tuzcu)'s answer, I created [flutter_cors](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cors) to make the process easier.

Comment: Hope this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72321040/17798537 can help you :)

Answer (score 349, accepted):

1- Go to `flutter\bin\cache` and remove a file named: `flutter_tools.stamp`

2- Go to `flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web` and open the file `chrome.dart`.

3- Find `'--disable-extensions'`

4- Add `'--disable-web-security'`

Comment: This works. thank you but I am getting this warning "You are using an unsupported comment-line... Stability and security will suffer.", should I be worried?

Comment: Don't worry @Becca because this works only your local without cors.

Comment: For Linux me the file was at `~/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/web/chrome.dart` BTW

Comment: And the other file: `sudo rm ~/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_tools.stamp`

Comment: :( when deploying to production, its showing error again

Comment: use this command for production
flutter build web --web-renderer html

Comment: @Sahid rahutomo This is not solution. Do you know how to works html render?

Comment: Not working on released flutter web build

Comment: I received a message the feature was not supported.

Comment: Not working on released flutter web build –

Comment: @scienticious have you found any solution for web build ??

Comment: I thought this solution isn't working for me. but then I noticed I hadn't put a comma after `--disable-web-security`

Comment: What does "Find '--disable-extensions'" mean? Should I delete it or should I just add the other line beneath it?

Comment: I have the same problem but. I don't want to disable web security measures. This solution does app put in danger ? On the other hand, customers will see a notification such as "this is not a safe app " or something similar?

Comment: This method for only development @isa

Comment: This won't work for production environments...the given snippet disables CORS only for the chrome browser on your pc for testing purposes, but if you publish your webpage, your client will have CORS activated (as it should be)

Comment: No need for weird workarounds since flutter 3.3.0., where you can add any web browser flag to the flutter command, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74783428/5164462

Comment: @Sahid rahutomo you should publish the Flutter web app on the same domain where your API is

Comment: Thank you for the solution on the local side.
For the production, you can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72321040/17798537.

Comment: i configure cors on my laravel project as backend

Comment: CAUTION! Disabling web security doesn't fix the CORS issue, it just disables a security feature locally on your machine! Use appropriate HTTP headers to tell the browser from where to accept http request.

Comment: How to make it works in Production, please?

Answer (score 134):

### Since Flutter 3.3.0

I [implemented the option to add any browser flag](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/104935) to the flutter command.

```bash
flutter run -d chrome --web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security"
```

Or for `drive` command:

```bash
flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart --target=integration_test/app_test.dart -d web-server --web-browser-flag="--disable-web-security"
```

**Note:** This is just for **development** and **testing**. Flutter is executed explicitly on the **client**'s browser! You should NOT and you can NOT disable it in **production** (as stated by @Tommy), as it is a security feature of the browser, and not meant to be changed in dart code. You have to [enable CORS on your **web server**](https://enable-cors.org/server.html), which is providing the resources of your Flutter app, to ensure it works for everyone.

*If you use dart language **without Flutter** on the server side with [shelf](https://github.com/dart-lang/samples/blob/master/server/simple/bin/server.dart), then see [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26253433/5164462).*

Comment: How can we use this flag in launch.json?

Comment: You can add `args` to your [launch config](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/vs-code#run-app-in-debug-profile-or-release-mode): `{"name": ..., "request": "launch", "type": "dart", "args": ["--web-browser-flag=--disable-web-security"]}`

Comment: is it possible to add this flag to run configuration in android studio?

Comment: Of course @Abdulaziz: just add the flag to the "Additional run args" in your Run configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64686348/5164462

Answer (score 25):

I think disabling web security as suggested will make you jump over the current error for now but when you go for production or testing on other devices the problem will persist because it is just a workaround, the correct solution is from the server side to allow CORS from the requesting domain and allow the needed methods, and credentials if needed.

Answer (score 15):

This is a CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) issue and you do not have to delete/modify anything. You just have to enable the CORS request from your server-side and it will work fine.

In my case, I have created a server with node.js and express.js, so I just added this middleware function that will run for every request.

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

And BOOOOM! I received the data.

You just have to look at the settings to enable CORS for your server.

Comment: The BOOOOM! adds something! :)

Answer (score 10):

run/compile your Flutter web project using web-renderer. This should solve the issue both locally and remotely:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
flutter build web --web-renderer html
```

Comment: Not working on remotely

Comment: Not working on local or production.

Comment: This solution worked but only in Chrome. Won't work in other browsers.

Comment: In production mode, not even in chrome. It will work only if your site is hosted in firebase hosting.

Comment: @ThiagoSilva I think you are correct- I've only tested this solution in Firebase Hosting.

Answer (score 8):

After hours of testing, the following works perfectly for me.

Add the following to the PHP file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

This allow the correct connection with the HTTP GET POST with no issue from flutter for me.

I discovered this in the following discussion:

[XMLHttpRequest error Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57421)

Comment: Thiiiiis one worked for me. Thaaanks

Comment: but i didn't use php to my flutter web.

Answer (score 7):

If you run a Spring Boot server, add "@CrossOrigin" to your Controller or to your service method.

```
@CrossOrigin
@PostMapping(path="/upload")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Void> upload(@RequestBody Object object) {
    // ...
}
```

I know the question explicitly asked for a solution "with dart code" only, but I was not able to fix the exception with dart code (for example by changing the header).

Answer (score 6):

march 2023 update

i'm using google cloud functions v2 on google cloud run for my functions. Instead of calling CORS-sensitive apis in my flutter client or running a whole node js client app, i'm calling my functions written in js(running on google cloud functions v2 node js 18 env). So that the only http.dart to make call to google cloud run will be the main process of flutter client, which would help the original problems to be solved. Of course there are fees for using google cloud run, but i believe the fees are quite reasonable to run the whole functions for our services [:

---

Server side engine like node js or django is really needed to work with flutter web with bunch of external apis. Actually there's high possibility of same CORS error when we try to use internal api because of the CORS mechanism related to port number difference.

There are bunch of steps and answers from SO contributors that recommend to use chrome extensions to avoid CORS errors, but that is actually not cool for users. All the users should download the browser extensions to use the single website from us, which wouldn't be there if we used true server engines.

CORS is from browser as far as i know, so our flutter ios and android apps with same api code don't give those CORS errors. First time i encountered this error with flutter web, i believed i can deal with CORS in my app code lines. But that is actually not healthy way for users and long term dev plans.

Hope all flutter web newbies understand that web is quite a wild field for us. Even though i'm also newbie here, i highly recommend all the flutter web devs from 1.22.n stable to learn server side engines like node js. It is worth try.

And if u came so far down to this line of my self-answer, here's a simple guide for flutter web with node js. Flutter web is on stable channel but all those necessary infra are not fully ready for newbies like me. So be careful when you first dive into web field, and hope you re-check all the conditions and requirements to find out if you really need web version of your flutter app, and also if you really need to do this work with flutter. And my answer was yes lol

https://blog.logrocket.com/flutter-web-app-node-js/

Comment: So what do we do when you use Firebase as the backend and still get the error?!

Comment: @SIMMORSAL i'm not pretty sure of what your Firebase-related error is. I've not gotten myself that far away combining node js engine and Firebase products. But if you've actually got through the error in a certain situation, then a new SO thread might be open with tags like flutter-web, cors, firebase, and firebase-<product-name>, and would be grateful if you comment the new thread's link here [:

Comment: I figured out the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/67830000/4457315 ... Thaanks anyways.

Answer (score 6):

The disabling web security approaches work well in development, but probably not so well in production. An approach that worked for me in production dart code involves avoiding the pre-flight CORS check entirely by keeping the web request simple. In my case this meant changing the request header to contain:

```
'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
```

Even though I'm actually sending json, setting it to text/plain avoids the pre-flight CORS check. The lambda function I'm calling didn't support pre-flight OPTIONS requests.

Here's some info on other ways to [keep a request simple](https://medium.com/@praveen.beatle/avoiding-pre-flight-options-calls-on-cors-requests-baba9692c21a) and avoid a pre-flight request

Answer (score 4):

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web-images

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
flutter build web --web-renderer html
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: n production mode, not even in chrome. It will work only if your site is hosted in firebase hosting.

Answer (score 3):

## Update:

I recommend to use [User Rebo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74783428/410996). It is now possible to pass `--disable-web-security` as a browser flag to run & drive commands!

---

## Original *outdated* answer:

---

##### Alternative solution for MacOS & Android Studio (without modifying Flutter source)

We use a similar approach as Osman Tuzcu. Instead of modifying the Flutter source code, we add the `--disable-web-security` argument in a shell script and just forward all other arguments that were set by Flutter. It might look overly complicated but it takes just a minute and there is no need to repeat it for every Flutter version.

##### 1. Run this in your terminal

```bash
echo '#!/bin/zsh
# See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/31150244/410996
trap "trap - SIGTERM && kill -- -$$" SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
set -e ; /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --test-type --disable-web-security "$@" ; set +e &
PID=$!
wait $PID
trap - SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
wait $PID
' > ~/chrome_launcher
chmod 755 ~/chrome_launcher
```

This adds a `chrome_launcher` script to your user folder and marks it executable.

##### 2. Add this line to your `.zshrc` (or `.bashrc` etc.):

```bash
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=~/chrome_launcher
```

##### 3. Restart Android Studio

If a simple restart does not work, use **Invalidate Caches / Restart** in Android Studio to force loading of changes.

##### Notes

The script also adds the `--test-type` flag to suppress the ugly warning about the disabled security features. Be aware that this option might also suppress other error messages!
The `CHROME_EXECUTABLE` takes only the path to an executable file it is not possible to set arguments there.
Without trapping exit signals and killing the process group, the Google Chrome instance was not killed when you hit the **Stop Button** in Android Studio.

Comment: Does it work on released web build of flutter?

Comment: For your production app you will have to set appropriate CORS headers on your files.

Comment: This won't work for production environments...the given snippet disables CORS only for the chrome browser on your pc for testing purposes, but if you publish your webpage, your client will have CORS activated (as it should be).

Comment: Of course it does not! (see my comment above) It would be dangerous if anyone could just disable important browser security features from their website...

Answer (score 3):

This official solution worked for me on Chrome only ([Source](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/web-renderers)). But I had to run it first every time.

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```

And disabling web security also worked ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66879350/15526921)). But the browsers will show a warning banner.

But In case you are running on a different browser than Chrome (*e.g. Edge*) and you want to keep 'web security' enabled.
**You can change the default web renderer in settings in VS Code**

> File ==> Preferences ==> Settings ==> Enter '*Flutter Web*' in the Search Bar ==> Set the default web renderer to **html**

Answer (score 3):

I am getting the same error with php api so i add the php code these lines ;

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [FVM](https://fvm.app), I suggest to use [`flutter_cors`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cors) package

```
dart pub global activate flutter_cors
fluttercors --disable
```

If you face

```
zsh: command not found: fluttercors
```

You need to add it to PATH. In my case, I'm using zsh, I add it to `.zshrc` by

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

Press `I` to start editing and paste `export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"` to the top of the file

[image]

Then press `ESC` and type `:wq` to save the `.zshrc` file.
Now you're good to go

[image]

Now, just need to run your flutter web normally. It will trigger Chrome without CORS.

Comment: This worked for me. However, it's worth noting that I had to pass the `--flutter-path=/root/dir/of/flutter/version` to `fluttercors` . Otherwise, at least under some conditions (mainly, if you have multiple versions are have not set some ENV vars), you'll get this error:

> $ fluttercors --disable 

```
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = './packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/web/chrome.dart' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

Comment: From the devs:

Note 
This script only disables CORS checks for local testing, and will not help with CORS issues in production. Do not ask for help with production CORS issues as that is outside the scope of this project.

Answer (score 2):

in my case, it was due to cors package was not used. I resolved it by following below steps

Install Cors

npm install cors

In Server.js file add cors import

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

// Use cors middleware to enable CORS
app.use(cors());

// ... rest of your server code
```

Place the `app.use(cors());` line before your route definitions to enable CORS for all routes.

After that save server file and close it. Now rerun your server

```
node server.js
```

And it resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may not doing this in right way.
The cors headers should be added in HTTP response header while you added them in you reuqest header obviously.

for more information check out the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#what_requests_use_cors

Answer (score 1):

The below solution is great if you are only communicating with a local NodeJS server.

1. [Install NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. Create a basic NodeJS express project

   - Create a folder to put you NodeJS project in

     - ex: `C:\node_project\`
     - in PowerShell run: `npm init` in the folder

       - fill in your desired values
       - `entry point:` must be `app.js` for this example to work
     - in PowerShell run: `npm install express` in the folder
     - create a `app.js` file in the folder

```js
// init express
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// set the path to the web build folder
app.use(express.static("C:/Users/your_username/path_to_flutter_app/build/web"));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

- The value `"C:/Users/your_username/path_to_flutter_app/build/web"` must be changed to the web build folder in your flutter app.
- The app can be accessed through your browser once the app is built, the node server is running, and the browser is at the correct address

  - Build the app

    - open PowerShell and navigate to the flutter project's root ex: `C:/Users/your_username/path_to_flutter_app/`
    - run `flutter build web`
  - turn on the node server

    - open PowerShell and navigate to the NodeJS server folder ex: `C:\node_project\`
    - run: `node app.js`
  - Open in your browser

    - Enter `http://localhost:8080/` into the browser

***Note that everytime you change your flutter app's dart code you will need to re-run `flutter build web`***

Answer (score 1):

### Wrong Server on Target Port

I feel silly for even admitting this, but I had some other local server running on the targeted port. I've no clue why the server seemed to boot on the same port, or why the iOS app seemed to work, but now that I'm hitting the actual server it's working fine.

I was also getting some 404's mixed in, but originally thought that was due to the CORs error.

Maybe someone else has this same issue and this helps them.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, The problem was in laravel backend code which did not support CORS, So I added the CORS into backend project then it worked successfully in test and live.

Answer (score 1):

The 5th step of [Osmans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66879350/9160670) should be to add the option

'--disable-site-isolation-trials',

Only this works for me.

Chrome version 106.0.5249.119

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33005128)

Answer (score 1):

It Worked With Me By The Following Code :
in **conn.php** file put like this :

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

$connect = new mysqli("localhost","db_user","db_password","db_name");

if($connect){
     
}else{
    echo "Connection Failed";
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me none of the solutions above worked on production as it was expected. Altough there is one solution I can suggest which uses CORS proxy to avoid CORS issues on flutter web on production. You can find CORS proxies on this [website](https://nordicapis.com/10-free-to-use-cors-proxies/).

Basically you bypass all the unnecessary headers which your browser appends to your requests, so you may not encounter the same CORS issues when making request to another API. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with django in the side of the service, you can configure CORS with 'corsheaders', in this link you can find whole the documentation to setup your back end and recognice your requests.

https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

Answer (score 1):

For development debugging purpose below solution worked for me (WIll NOT WORK FOR PRODUCTION)

1. Delete flutter_tools.stamp file exists in below location
   flutter\bin\cache
2. Open chrome.dart which exists in below location
   flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web
3. Find '--disable-extensions' line & add below line after that with comma
   '--disable-web-security',
4. Go to your proj & hit flutter upgrade & pub get (Tools>Flutter>) in android studio

Comment: Saves life in development environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) issue and you just need to enable the CORS request from your server-side.

In my case it is *Asp.Net MVC Web API* and adding below code to `Application_BeginRequest` at `Global.asax` worked for me:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:7777/");

if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
{
    //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Use desired *urls* , *Methods* and *Headers*

Also There is no need to change anything in *Web.config*

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking for an equivalent of the accepted answer (Osman's) when working with [dart web](https://dart.dev/web) (webdev), here's what worked for me on Dart 2.17.6 (a bit more complex but in case you needed a quick fix, it might be handful).

1. Find webdev executable ([this helps](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-global#running-a-script-from-your-path)) then you see something like this:

[image: webdev]

The snapshot file (generated if not exist, as you see) is executed when you want to run app in browser. It contains the code that dart runs when launching chrome (using `browser_launcher` dart package).

2. Backup and remove the snapshot file (location in the screenshot above) so it can be regenerated in next run.
3. Locate `browser_launcher` package in your [pub cache](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/environment-variables) (also you might find location of `browser_launcher` by searching in the snapshot file) and edit `lib\src\chrome.dart`, find `'--disable-extensions'` and add `'--disable-web-security'`.
4. Run your app and remove the backup created in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to flutter\bin\cache and remove a file named: flutter_tools.stamp
2. Go to flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web and open the file chrome.dart.
3. Find '--disable-extensions'
4. Add '--disable-web-security'

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I needed to run my flutter app in production as a chrome web app. The ultimate solution was to create a cloud function that routed the API call.

You can explore Firebase or whatever backend service you use to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

While answer given by Osman Tuzcu works perfectly, you can now also use [flutter_cors](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cors)

package to achieve this. Using this you don't have to manually do these steps instead you can just use `fluttercors --disable` `--enable` flags

Answer (score -3):

**USE THIS**

```
http.post('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://kapi.kakao.com/v1/payment/ready', ... )
```

It's work fine for me !!

from (cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com)