# How chrome extensions be enabled when flutter web debugging?

Tags: flutter, google-chrome-extension, flutter-web

On flutter web debuggin opening a new window without chrome extensions. But my project must messaging with extensions. How can I prevent disablings at chrome extensions?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43809

Comment: I tried these before asking, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 12):

1- Go to flutter\bin\cache and remove a file named: flutter_tools.stamp

2- Go to flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web and open the file chrome.dart.

3- Find '--disable-extensions' and comment the line

4- Run 'flutter clean' (no 100% sur its needed)

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66879350

Comment: Thank you so much. And no the step 4 (flutter clean) is not needed.

Comment: But this only works on debug mode

Answer (score 5):

The only way you can do this is by recompiling flutter entirely, without the disable extensions flag.

It's a huge problem for everybody. I can't even test any WEB3 apps, because metamask is also not possible to use. I think google did it purposely.

Comment: You don't have to recompile it.  Follow the instructions above, which are copied from the original post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630743  By removing the timestamp file and modifying the script to remove the disable flag the next time you run flutter it will "rebuild" the tool for you.  (It's easy).