# POST request gets blocked on Python backend. GET request works fine

Tags: python, flutter, flask, post, cors

I am building a web app where the front-end is done with Flutter while the back-end is with Python.
GET requests work fine while POST requests get blocked because of CORS, I get this error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/signal' from origin 'http://localhost:57765' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Below is my flutter function I used to send GET and POST requests:

```
  Future<dynamic> sendResponse() async {
    final url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/signal';
    var data = {
      "signal": '8',
    };
    var header = {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      "Accept": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded, '*'"
    };


    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: data, headers: header);//http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: data, headers: header);//http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(json.decode(response.body));
      return jsonDecode(response.body);
      //print(json.decode(credentials.body));
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
      throw Exception('Failed to load Entry');
    }

   // var ResponseFromPython = await response.body;//jsonDecode(credentials.body);

   // return ResponseFromPython;
  }
```

Below is my Python backend code using Flask:

```
   from flask import Flask,jsonify, request, make_response
   import json


   from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin


   #declared an empty variable for reassignment
   response = ''

   app = Flask(__name__)

   #CORS(app, resources={r"/signal": {"origins": "*, http://localhost:59001"}}) 
   #http://localhost:52857
   #CORS(app, origins=['*'])
   app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = ['Content-Type','Authorization']



   @app.route("/")
   def index():
    
    return "Congratulations, it worked"

   @app.route("/signal", methods = ['POST', 'GET']) #,
   @cross_origin(origins='http://localhost:57765',headers=['Content-Type','Authorization', 
   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','*'], upports_credentials=True)# allow all origins all 
   methods.
   def multbytwo():
       """multiple signal by 2 just to test."""
       global response
       if (request.method=='POST'):
       # request.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
           request_data = request.data #getting the response data
           request_data = json.loads(request_data.decode('utf-8')) #converting it from json to key 
   value pair
           comingSignal = request_data['signal']
           response = make_response(comingSignal, 201)#jsonify(comingSignal*2)
           response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
           response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS')
           response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, X- 
  Requested-With')
           return response
       else:
           try:
        #scaler = request.args.get("signal")
               out = 9 * 2 
         
               response = jsonify(out)
               response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") 
               return response #sending data back to your frontend app

           except ValueError:
               return "invalid input xyz"

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

Below are the troubleshooting steps I made:
**-Added the flask_CORS package in python**
I tried here different combination from using general parameters like `CORS(app, resources={r"/signal": {"origins": "*"}})`  did not help. Also tried the decorator `@cross-origin` and did not help

**-Added some headers to the response itself to indicate that it accepts cross-origin**
You see in my python code I tried adding a lot of headers to the response, nothing seem to respond.

**-Tried installing an extension in Chrome that by-passes the CORS check**
I tried the `allow CORS` and `CORS unblock` extensions and I used the steps described in this answer: [How chrome extensions be enabled when flutter web debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67958169/how-chrome-extensions-be-enabled-when-flutter-web-debugging). Although these extensions are supposed to add the CORS allow header to the response, I still got the same error.

I still do not fully understand the CORS concept but I tried a lot of work-arounds and nothing works! please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on.
**First I disabled the same origin policy in chrome using this command:** this is run clicking the start button in windows and typing this command directly..

```
chrome.exe  --disable-site-isolation-trials --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="D:\anything"
```

This fired a separate chrome window that does not block cross-origin, we will call this the CORS free window. This allowed me to finally communicate with my python code and understand what is going on.
[image: You can see the]

You can see that the chrome default setting were not even showing me anything related to the response, just showing a 500 code error.

**I copied the localhost link and port and pasted them in my other CORS free chrome window**
The other CORS free chrome window showed helpful information:
[image]

**It was a simple JSON decoding error!** I went back to my flutter code and I changed the http post request, adding a `jsonEncode` function on the post body:

```
http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body:jsonEncode(data), headers: header);
```

Now the post request returns a correct response on the default chrome settings.
[image]
It was just this CORS blocking the response completely that made me handi-capped.

Answer (score 3):

Flask has an `@app.after_request` decorator, this helped me to ensure the headers get added, regardless of what happens in the route

```
@app.after_request
def add_cors_headers(resp):
    resp.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    resp.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
    resp.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS')
```

This solved the CORS issues in my case!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you clarify if there is a specific location in the code where this decorator should be placed? I tried to put it before and after my `@app.route` decorator but both did not work. Should I define a global variable called response and use it in both the response function and the `@app.after_request` decorator?

Comment: I have this in the same file that has the app.run function. The decorator makes sure that the function below it (add_cors_headers in this case) will be run after every request. You dont need a global variable "resp", that is given to that function by flask automatically

Answer (score 0):

Add below line to your header map

{
"....":"...."
"Accept": "*/*"
.
.
.
}