# Not able to fetch data from my own API in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, http

I am not able to fetch data from my own API in flutter, but yes I am able to fetch data from fake API such as http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: RequestPage(),
    );
  }
}

class RequestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RequestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RequestPage> createState() => _RequestPageState();
}

class _RequestPageState extends State<RequestPage> {
  Future<void> getdata() async {
    var res = await http
        .get(Uri.parse("https://myurl.com/api/"));
    print(res.body);
  }

  late String username;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: getdata,
                child: Text("Make A Request"),
              ),
              Text("Response")
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My API:

```
<?php


header("Access-Control_Allow_Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8"); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");

$conn  = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "api");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
header('Content-Type:application/json');
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($arr);
}

?>
```

Output that I want:

```
[
{
id: "1",
username: "admin",
password: "123456",
},
]
```

Error that I am getting:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 906:28                get current
    packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 69:22                                       <fn>
    dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1687:54                                              runUnary
    dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 160:18                                        handleValue
    dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 767:44                                        handleValueCallback
    dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 796:13                                        _propagateToListeners
    dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 593:7                                         [_complete]
    dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
    dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1288:7                                             <fn>
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall
    dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 339:39  dcall
    dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37254:58                              <fn>
        at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:56929/dart_sdk.js:5076:12)
        at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:56929/dart_sdk.js:40477:16)
        at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:56929/dart_sdk.js:40473:13)
        at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:56929/dart_sdk.js:40330:13)
        at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:56929/dart_sdk.js:40336:13)
        at http://localhost:56929/dart_sdk.js:35811:9
```

Please help me

Comment: That looks more like a php problem. Did you check (for example with a browser since it's a simple GET call) what your output actually looks like?

Comment: This is a CORS error caused by a typo in your header here: `header("Access-Control_Allow_Origin: *");`

Answer (score 0):

That flutter code looks right.

Like @Richard pointed out `header("Access-Control_Allow_Origin: *")` should be `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`.

Also double check that you're replacing "https://myurl.com/api/" with your correct URL.

Comment: thanks for helping me but the real problem is of chrome i found the solution of it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630743/how-to-solve-flutter-web-api-cors-error-only-with-dart-code