# Request http in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to post data to the server with dio library but when I send data, I get `XMLHttpRequest error`. The server programmer checked twice his codes and made sure to enable CORS in the server. I think this error occurs because the server is not `HTTPS` and the browser blocks the request. I use this code to send my data to the server:

```
Response response = await client
        .post(theUrl,
            options: Options(
                validateStatus: (status) {
                  return status! < 500;
                },
                followRedirects: false,
                headers: {
                  HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
                  HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: "*/*",
                  HttpHeaders.accessControlAllowOriginHeader:
                      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Accept",
                }),
            data: convert.json.encode(data))
        .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10));
```

My log is just:

```
DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: XMLHttpRequest error.
```

So, How can I ignore the certificate of the server host and send data to an HTTP URL in flutter web?

Comment: Always add error logs

Comment: @griffins it's just one line and I added it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that the problem is because your server doesn't have an https certificate.
A workaround is run / debug your application with flutter desktop.

You can also take a look at: [How to solve flutter web api cors error only with dart code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630743/how-to-solve-flutter-web-api-cors-error-only-with-dart-code/66879350#66879350)