# How to check where exactly VS Code runs the app via a browser?

Tags: flutter

I use VS Code as an editor. I've tried to do ways of avoiding it with the help of [answers on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630743/how-to-solve-flutter-web-api-cors-error-only-with-dart-code) and [discussions from github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46904), but nonetheless it didn't work for me. How to check where exactly VS Code runs the browser? I need this because editing chrome.dart script didn't work.

Comment: What is your actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @derpirscher I'm trying to solve CORS problem