# Flutter Web - Error code: XML Http Request Error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to fetch a simple JSON file from my HTTPS server in flutter web however, it doesn't fetch the JSON and simply prints :-

```
Error code: XMLHTTPRequest error
```

How do I fix this issue? Here's my code -

```
Future<List<GamesJSON>> fetch(String link) async {
    final res = await get(Uri.parse(link));
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(res.body);
      final rest = data;
      list = rest.map<GamesJSON>((json) => GamesJSON.fromJson(json)).toList()
          as List<GamesJSON>;
    } 
    return list;
  }
```

Comment: Did you test the GET API on postman? It could be a CORS issue.

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630743/how-to-solve-flutter-web-api-cors-error-only-with-dart-code/66879350#66879350

Comment: @MuhammadHussain yes it works fine on android and ios but issue is with flutter web. and I tried disabling cors, but it won't work

Comment: If it works on android and ios, then it makes more sense to say it's a CORS issue, you need to allow CORS from your backend side. Looks less like a flutter issue.

Comment: However, the source I am calling from is not from my own server/backend

Comment: This only fixes CORS on my localhost, but in production this solution doesn't work @MuhammadHussain

Answer (score -1):

You need to change this line

```
list = rest.map<GamesJSON>((json) => GamesJSON.fromJson(json)).toList()
          as List<GamesJSON>;
```

to this

`List<GamesJSON> list = rest.map<GamesJSON>((json) => GamesJSON.fromJson(json)).toList();`

Comment: List is already defined, and this has no co-relation with flutter web.

Comment: Then your fromJson method cannot be correct.

Comment: It works just fine on android and ios