# Recaptcha v3 return blocked by CORS policy

Tags: flutter, dart, recaptcha, flutter-web, recaptcha-v3

Im implementing recaptcha v3 for my flutter web project,

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I already add the localhost inside the settings, do i need to do other settings in order for this to solve?

Answer (score 0):

As the stackoverflow response [flutter-web-cors-problem-solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630743/how-to-solve-flutter-web-api-cors-error-only-with-dart-code) says the followings and it is working fine for me;

1- Go to flutter\bin\cache and remove a file named: flutter_tools.stamp

2- Go to flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web and open the file chrome.dart.

3- Find '--disable-extensions'

4- Add '--disable-web-security'

Comment: I have the same problem but. I don't want to disable web security measures. It does app put in danger ?