# not able to access json file in flutter api call

Tags: flutter

I want to use JSON from this link https://howtodoandroid.com/movielist.json.

This is my code where I want to call API from the above link

```dart
Future getMovieList() async {

final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://howtodoandroid.com/movielist.json"));
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  allMovielist = jsonDecode(response.body);
 
  
    }
}
```

i got error "failed to load response data: no data found for resource with given identifier"

Answer (score 1):

```
Future<List<YourModel>> getMovieList() async {
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://howtodoandroid.com/movielist.json"));
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  /// On first the data will get is always unassigned or just dynamic
  /// which cant be identify 
  final List<dynamic> list = jsonDecode(response.body);
   /// try to print or log the data if the data goes to status 200 and able
   /// to see it
   log(list.map((e) => e).toList().toString());
   /// this one will return the indicate assigned data
   return list.map((e)=> YourModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
  } else{
  return [];
 }
}
```

Comment: can i do it without model @Arbiter Chil

Comment: yess you can just pass the list since it dynamic just remove List<YourModel> on the future and on the return just put the list which is the dynamic

Comment: Not working yet. getting CORS error. please help

Comment: can you include the error image on the question

Comment: Are you trying this on flutter web?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying this on the web run this command `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html`

if you still get a CROS error **disable the web security**.

1- Go to `flutter\bin\cache` and remove a file named: `flutter_tools.stamp`

2- Go to `flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web` and open the file `chrome.dart`.

3- Find `'--disable-extensions'`

4- Add `'--disable-web-security'`

I get this answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630743/how-to-solve-flutter-web-api-cors-error-only-with-dart-code)

or consider this  [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cors) also

Example Code

```
 Future getMoviesList() async {
    var headers = <String, String>{'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
    var url = Uri.parse('https://howtodoandroid.com/movielist.json');
    var response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var result = json.decode(response.body);
      print(result);
      return result;
    }
  }
```