# How to reenable web security for Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, api, request

## Issue

I constantly see a message when running my Flutter projects on web:

> You are using unsupported command-line flag; --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer.

This issue started from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66879350/14299091), because I set this flag on development (later it turned out it's only working on dev, but not on production).

## What I tried

[Undoing the changes discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66879350/14299091)

- restore the deleted file named `flutter_tools.stamp` at `flutter\bin\cache`
- remove the added line from `flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web`: `'--disable-web-security'`
- `dart pub cache repair`
- `flutter clean`
- restart computer / Vscode

None of the things worked that I tried. Should I reinstall the whole flutter or is there something simpler I can try?

Answer (score 2):

1- Go to flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web and open the file chrome.dart.
2 - Remove '--disable-web-security'
3 - Go to flutter\bin\cache and remove a file named: flutter_tools.stamp

Worked for me, had exactly the same problem.