# Flutter: error code: XmlHTTPRequest Error

Tags: node.js, flutter, google-cloud-platform, xmlhttprequest

When I run the command `flutter run -d chrome --web-port 3000`
There I always see an "XMLHttpRequest Error" in Chrome.

[Error displayed in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O3Xw.png)

It says:

> The OAuth token was not passed to gapi.client, since the gapi.client
> library is not loaded in your page.

I didn't find any answers here referring to this problem.

Has anybody encountered this problem and been able to solve it?

I attempted all of the methods outlined in another post, [How to solve flutter web api cors error only with dart code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630743/how-to-solve-flutter-web-api-cors-error-only-with-dart-code/66879350#66879350), but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Have you enabled the _People API_ in your GCP project?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the exception is *misleading*, and if you look at the network traffic, you should see a `403` response from GCP complaining about how the *People API* is not enabled on the project.

There's a link in the error message to do that, enable the API, wait five minute for the change to propagate, and you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to Google cloud and inside API navigate to service details and enable People Api It's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

- your domain must start with https (ssl).
- must add your domain to google: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials [OAuth 2.0 Client IDs]