# Creating a build version for flutter web shows an empty page

Tags: flutter

I have a basic flutter website that works fine in localhost when doing `flutter run -d chrome`, but when I was ready to publish it, with the command `flutter build web`, it shows a blank page and throw some generic errors by console.

[Console errors on developer options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJnCu.png)

Checking other answers such as change the href on the index.html page aren't working.
Running flutter doctor -v is showing this error, which I can't find anything useful about, but the website cocoapods that is referencing is not available

`[!] HTTP Host Availability X HTTP host "https://cocoapods.org/" is not reachable. Reason: Failed to connect to host in 10 seconds`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer Adedokun,

So, turns out I'm still learning, and the index.html page is never going to work alone, according to the documentation [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/web), you need to go to the folder root and launch a server by console, in this case I did with `python -m http.server 8000`, and navigated in a browser to localhost:8000, then go to build, then web.
Also, in the /build/web index.html, needed to change the href="/" to href="./" so it could work finally, it appears that href="" works too.
I hope this helps someone too.

and about the Availability, it was just temporal, this morning the flutter doctor didn't show any error :)

Answer (score 0):

This has to deal with CORS error. one way of fixing this by using the HTML renderer.

```
flutter build web --web-renderer html
```

or try the solutions here. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630743/how-to-solve-flutter-web-api-cors-error-only-with-dart-code)