# Can we use --disable-web-security in flutter web for production?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on small project of flutter web creation but always show CORS error, then i use --disable-web-security in chrome.dart file in flutter, then every thing is proper working but my doubt is it is also working in production time or not , please reply me.

I tried --disable-web-security add in chrome.dart file in flutter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve flutter web api cors error only with dart code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630743/how-to-solve-flutter-web-api-cors-error-only-with-dart-code)

Comment: The flag in question should only be used for development and testing and you cannot disable it in production.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not.

More Details:
CORS is enforced by the web browser running your app. Hence, every user would need to disable it manually on their browser.
To fix the CORS error, you need to tell the web request library of your choice to allow certain actions on specific domains.

For example:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", // CAUTION: Better specify your exact domain
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, ....,
```

The chrome.dart file you've mentioned would only influence your local chrome instance you use to run the app and will not have any effects on your productive user's environment.

I hope this helps