# Flutter webview_universal: ^0.0.5 connection refused in web

Tags: flutter

I want to build an app with webview_universal: ^0.0.5 on Android, IOS, Web, windows, linux, macos

It works when I load "https://flutter.dev"

But when I change the url to "https://www.google.com" , the web will come the error connection refused in web.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import "package:webview_universal/webview_universal.dart";

class HomePage3 extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage3({super.key});



  @override
  State<HomePage3> createState() => _HomePage3State();
}

class _HomePage3State extends State<HomePage3> {
  WebViewController webViewController = WebViewController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    task();

  }

   Future<void> task() async {
    await webViewController.init(
      setState: (fn) {
        
      },
      context: context,
      uri: Uri.parse("https://google.com"),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
      
        controller: webViewController,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It happens by CORS protection. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630743/how-to-solve-flutter-web-api-cors-error-only-with-dart-code