expected a value of type javascriptobject but got one of type FirebaseException
Tried to change package dependencies like :
firebase_core_web: 2.10.0
firebase_auth_web: 5.8.13
cloud_firestore_web: 3.9.0
Tried another set of dependencies but didn't work :
cloud_firestore: 4.10.0
firebase_auth: 4.11.0
firebase_core: 2.18.0
Integrated Firebase Authentication with the rest of the code but didn't work and error first appeared because of that.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';



void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Healthcare App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: AuthenticationScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthenticationScreenState createState() => _AuthenticationScreenState();
}

class _AuthenticationScreenState extends State<AuthenticationScreen> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Healthcare App - Sign In'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _isLoading
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: _emailController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Email',
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: _passwordController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Password',
                    ),
                    obscureText: true,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _signInWithEmailAndPassword();
                    },
                    child: Text('Sign In'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _signInWithEmailAndPassword() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _emailController.text.trim(),
        password: _passwordController.text.trim(),
      );
      User? user = userCredential.user;
      if (user != null) {
        // Navigate to the patient home screen upon successful sign-in
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PatientHomeScreen(user: user)),
        );
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('Sign in failed. Please try again.'),
        ));
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('${e.message}'),
      ));
    } catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('Error: ${e.toString()}'),
      ));
    } finally {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }
}

class PatientHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;

  const PatientHomeScreen({Key? key, required this.user}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Patient Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('Welcome, ${user.email}!'),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Navigate to the symptom tracking screen
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SymptomTrackingScreen()),
                );
              },
              child: Text('Track Symptoms'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SymptomTrackingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SymptomTrackingScreenState createState() => _SymptomTrackingScreenState();
}

class _SymptomTrackingScreenState extends State<SymptomTrackingScreen> {
  // Add variables for symptom tracking
  TextEditingController _symptomController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _noteController = TextEditingController();

  // Function to handle saving symptom data
  void _saveSymptomData() {
    // Implement saving data to a database or cloud storage
    // For simplicity, let's just print the entered data for now
    print('Symptom: ${_symptomController.text}');
    print('Note: ${_noteController.text}');
    // Reset text controllers
    _symptomController.clear();
    _noteController.clear();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Symptom Tracking'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _symptomController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Symptom',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            TextField(
              controller: _noteController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Note',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _saveSymptomData,
              child: Text('Save'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


It seems like you may need to disable web security: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78159230/instance-of-clientexception-type-clientexception-is-not-a-subtype-of-type?rq=2

Frank van Puffelen No disabling web security didn't work
