Access-Control-Allow-Origin not added in rest API from Spring Boot application
I create a new Spring boot application with "Spring web" dependency. The template used version 3.2.5 of Spring boot. Relevant dependencies are:
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


After creating a rest controller I got Error: ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., in my Dart / Flutter client. Accessing the URL in the browser works fine and returns a JSON.
After reading about the problem I think the  Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing in the server configuration.
I tried adding it to the controller:
package com.vogella.spring.jsonserver;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.vogella.spring.jsonserver.controller.TutorialCategoryProvider;
import com.vogella.spring.jsonserver.model.TutorialCategory;
import com.vogella.spring.jsonserver.model.TutorialLink;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class CategoryController {

    private final TutorialCategoryProvider provider;

    @Autowired
    public CategoryController(TutorialCategoryProvider yourService) {
        this.provider = yourService;
    }
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @GetMapping("/categories")
    public List<TutorialCategory> get() {
        // Your implementation to fetch all links from your data source
        // For example, from a database or a service
        return provider.getTutorialCategories();
    }
    
}


And also tried to add this to the configuration of the application:
package com.vogella.spring.jsonserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                System.out.println("Called");
                
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .maxAge(4800)
                .allowCredentials(false)
                .allowedMethods("POST", "GET", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT")
                .allowedHeaders("origin", "Content-Type", "X-Requested-With", "X-File-Name", "x-mime-type",
                        "Accept-Encoding", "Authorization", "Content-Range", "Content-Disposition",
                        "Content-Description", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers");
            }
        };
    }

}

But if I check for this header via curl I do not see it:
curl -I http://localhost:8080/categories
HTTP/1.1 200 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2024 11:37:39 GMT

Any suggestions what I missed?

You are looking in the wrong place.
The browser sends an OPTIONS request before the actual request to get some information about the endpoint being called. The response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin is returned by the OPTIONS request, not the following GET request. The OPTIONS request the browser sends beforehand can also be replicated with curl:
curl --verbose --request OPTIONS "[endpoint being called]" --header "Origin: [host from which the endpoint is being called]" --header "Access-Control-Request-Method: [http method with which the endpoint is being called]"

So, in your case, the command line looks like this:
curl --verbose --request OPTIONS "http://localhost:8080/categories" --header "Origin: localhost:8080" --header "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET"

I assumed that the Spring Boot application serves the frontend as well as the API. If your frontend/client is served somewhere else, the Origin header has to be adjusted accordingly.
I have set up a small demo application based on your example and the curl command gives this output:
*   Trying [::1]:8080...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080
> OPTIONS /categories HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: localhost:8080
> Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 4800
< Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Thu, 25 Apr 2024 21:27:40 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

Please keep in mind that if you add security to your API, i.e. once your API requires credentials for authentication, the wildcard is not allowed for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header anymore and you have to specify all the possible referrer host names explicitly.

Thanks @derJoerg this shows the correct header. For reasons unknown to me, my Flutter clients still refuses to connect to to the client but I learned from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630743/how-to-solve-flutter-web-api-cors-error-only-with-dart-code that I can (during development) turn this check off with flutter run -d chrome --web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security"
