XMLHttpRequest error on Dartpad and all web apps but not on Mobile phones or Simulators
I was running a simple test using DartPad and it wasn't working. So I tried running on my Android phone using Visual Studio Code and a USB cable and it worked fine. Then I tried on an Android Simulator thru VSC and it works. I tried it via VSC on Chrome and Edge and it failed and tried it on Windows and it worked.
Here is the code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
//import 'package:logging/logging.dart';

final filename = <String>[
  "https://ListeningToGod.org/SermonEngagement/TextFiles/2024-10-130Ia.json",
  "https://ListeningToGod.org/SermonEngagement/TextFiles/2024-10-1301a.json",
  "https://ListeningToGod.org/SermonEngagement/TextFiles/2024-10-1302a.json",
  "https://ListeningToGod.org/SermonEngagement/TextFiles/2024-10-1303a.json",
  "https://ListeningToGod.org/SermonEngagement/TextFiles/2024-10-1304a.json",
  "https://ListeningToGod.org/SermonEngagement/TextFiles/2024-10-1305a.json",
  "https://ListeningToGod.org/SermonEngagement/TextFiles/2024-10-1306a.json",
  "https://ListeningToGod.org/SermonEngagement/TextFiles/2024-10-1307a.json",
  "https://ListeningToGod.org/SermonEngagement/TextFiles/2024-10-1308a.json",
  "https://ListeningToGod.org/SermonEngagement/TextFiles/2024-10-1309a.json",
];

void myLog(String s) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
//    final log = Logger('checkUrl');
//    log.shout(s);
    print(s);
  }
}
Map <String,String>? userHeader = {"Content-type": "text/plain",
                                   "Accept": "application/json","Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true','Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'OPTIONS, GET, POST','Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control'};
Future<bool> _checkUrl(String url) async {
  try {
    http.Response urlResponse = await http.get(Uri.parse(url),
    headers: userHeader,
  );
    myLog("File = $url Status code = ${urlResponse.statusCode}");
    return ((urlResponse.statusCode == 200) ? true : false);
  } catch (error) {
    myLog("Catch Error$error");
  }
  return false;
}

Future<int> getMaxEngagementIndex() async {
  int index = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < filename.length; i++) {
    String engagementFileName = filename[i];
    try {
      bool filePresent = await _checkUrl(engagementFileName);
      if (filePresent) {
        myLog("Got File $engagementFileName");
        index++;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      myLog("Catch = $error");
    }
  }
  return index;
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  int numfiles = await getMaxEngagementIndex();
  String num = numfiles.toString();
  runApp(MyApp(num));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String numfiles;
  const MyApp(this.numfiles, {super.key});
  Text seText(String text, double size, Color? color) {
    return Text(
      text,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: color,
        fontSize: size,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: seText('Num Files =$numfiles', 30, Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Based on the error messages from Dartpad and various questions on StackOverflow, I tried various headers and none seem to rid me of the error.
Here is the Exception I get in Dartpad:
Catch ErrorClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., uri=https://listeningtogod.org/SermonEngagement/TextFiles/XXX.json
Where XXX is each json filename.
The http package in flutter says that it should work on the Web - but I am not getting it to work.
Any help out there on this one?

Finally, I am making some progress. I have verified that this is a CORs issue (didn't even know what this was before). But now the code runs in Chrome from VSC. The solution was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630743/how-to-solve-flutter-web-api-cors-error-only-with-dart-code. You need to delete a flutter_tools.stamp file in your flutter sdk and add an unsupported (you will get a warning from Chrome) flag --disable-web-security in the chrome.dart file in your flutter sdk. I still don't know why this doesn't work in dartpad. But I suspect you cannot change these thing there.

CORS is there for security and is enforced at the server, so I am afraid that what you are doing here will only work locally, i.e. cannot work when you run your web app in production.
