# Is release mode flutter web app safe for user?

Tags: flutter

**Current Situation**

Made flutter web app and deploied it. I built release mode using code below.

```
flutter build web --web-renderer html --release
```

Purpose for release build was to deal with cors problem.
[Solution sorces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68936065/19464995)

**Question**

Is webapp build in release mode lack any security function compare to normal build?

```
flutter build web
```

I seen documentation but I could not find anything about security. Web app will be used by my client so I would like to keep it safe for them.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes says "Use release mode when you are ready to release your app", so it's presumably the safest of the options.